# how does this regex for email address validation work?

Tags: regex, email-validation, capturing-group, regex-group

While searching for regular expressions used for email address validation, i came across this page: http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html. i couldn't understand it.

> it says: \b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@(?:[A-Z0-9-]+.)+[A-Z]{2,4}\b  will match john@server.department.company.com but not john@aol...com.

Can you explain how `(?:[A-Z0-9-]+\.)` works in detail and how it doesn't match `john@aol...com` and matches the other one?

Comment: it is non-capturing, so the author of this regex felt that there is no need to put that into a capturing group, for better speed

Comment: so, here, it is just for the speed of the expression, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the appearance of a `.` is only once, so multiple `.` will not be matched.  For `..` or `...` etc to be matched, it would have to be `\.+` (the `+` means once or more, and is the same as `{1,}`

The regex says `(?:[A-Z0-9-]+\.)+` so it is one or more alphanumeric (or underscore), with a dot, and this whole thing can repeat once or more, so `c.c.c.` will match, but `c..c.c.` will not.

The `(?:   )` is non-capturing, and is usually faster.  You can use `(  )` and it works as well, but just slower and the matched text will go into the capturing group.

Comment: The link burhan provides explicitly mentions that the case-insensitive option needs to be enabled for this regex. Case-sensitivity is not the problem here.

Comment: Should note multiple `.` are not valid after the `@` in email address' so you wouldn't want `john@aol...com` to match!